# How can I animate a calculated position with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a variable with a calculated position that centers the element with JQuery, reason I did this is because I will not know the width of the element so I made it dynamic like so.

```
var $x = $("#line").outerWidth();

var $result = "calc( 50% - " + $x +"px / 2 )";
```

Then I tried to animate it to the center (value of $result) like so:

```
   $("#line").animate({ 
        "left": $result,
        "top" : "15px"

    }, 1000 );
```

Sadly this did not work, only the top value moved.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vijexa/3/)***

If you already use `calc` (CSS3) than you'll have nothing against using in your CSS:

### Using CSS3 `transition` and `calc()`

```
#line{
    transition: 1s;
    /*...other stuff...*/
}
```

and in your jQuery (instead of `.animate()`)

```
var outW2 = $("#line").outerWidth() / 2;

$("#line").css({ 
  left : "calc(50% - "+ outW2 +"px)",
  top  : 70
});
```

---

### Using `.animate()` and negative margin (for centering)

For all **older browsers**, you can simply use `.animate()` **as you did**,
moving the element to 50% but also to a **`-`half-width left margin** (to center it):

```
var outW2 = $("#line").outerWidth() / 2;

$("#line").animate(){
  left: "50%",
  marginLeft : -outW2
}, 1000);
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vijexa/4/edit?html,css,js,output)*** (crossbrowser solution)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it's the animation time. Notice how he uses 1000ms in jQuery, I use `transition: 1s;` in CSS

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am well aware that I can do this with the jquery css method. But I have to animate it with the jquery animate method for this one. Is there a way I can do it with jquery animate even if I do not use css3 calc?

Comment: @LucasSantos yes, added an additional note to my answer.

Comment: @LucasSantos added a demo too :)

Comment: Wow thanks, im going to test it out. Really appercaite it Roko

Comment: @LucasSantos you're welcome. Good luck with your project

Comment: Can't believe  I didnt think about animating a negative margin haha, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's animate won't accept the css3 `calc` as a valid pixel value.  You'll need to first calculate what `50%` is.

```
var containerWidth = $("#line").parent().outerWidth();
```

Then use that in your `$result`.

```
var $result = containerWidth * 0.5 - $x * 0.5;
```

This should give you the horizontal pixel location to animate it to.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same as using `calc()` as if any resize happens you'd need to recalculate the value again with javascript.

Comment: This actually isn't bad at all and works for my purpose because there is no resizing for me. Thanks for the response earl. I think im going with Roko's awnser only because he gave me 2 different options for cross browser compatibility. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, different way of tackling it.